# Angular ngModelOptions or setting variable to ngModel

Tags: angular

I have this piece of code:

```
<div *ngFor="let attrKey of attributeArr">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="attrKey">
</div>
```

I want to pass variable to ngModel. Is there anything like **ngModelOptions** or additional options to let this happen?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `let arrtKey of attributeArr` means two things

1. attributeArr is an array
2. in [(ngModel)]="attrKey" you change an element of array (and the
   array is an array of strings)

If you want iterate over the keys of an object, you can [use keyvalue pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) to mannage objects or create an auxiliar variable with the keys

Using keyvalue, we need be carefull, some like

```
<!--DONT WORK-->
<div *ngFor="let item of myobject | keyvalue">
  <input [(ngModel)]=myobject[item.key]>
</div>
```

Because each change Angular try repaint the loop -so you loose the focus-. For avoid it, you need use [trackBy](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) (or iterate over another auxiliar variable). Using trackBy

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myobject | keyvalue; trackBy: trackByFn">
  <input [(ngModel)]="myobject[item.key]">
</div>

//and in .ts you write
trackByFn=(_,item)=>item.key
```

The other option is defined in your .ts

```
keys=Object.kets(this.myObject)
```

And use

```
<div *ngFor="let item of keys">
  <input [(ngModel)]="myobject[item]">
</div>
```

See [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dazc4q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)